# Android custom soft keyboard - change KEYCODE_ENTER behavior to skip non EditText object like default soft keyboard behavior

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-softkeyboard

Follow this sample
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/
, I have my own soft keyboard.
I want to modify KEYCODE_ENTER behavior.

Example: I have my activity A with its layout layout_A: 
 EditText edt_1 + CheckBox chb_1 + EditText edt_2

The behavior of Android default soft keyboard:

```
focus edt_1 > KEYCODE_ENTER > skip chb_1 > focus edt_2 >> what I want
```

My soft keyboard:

```
focus edt_1 > KEYCODE_ENTER > focus chb_1 >> FAIL
```

Any one have source code of Android default soft keyboard? (with layout of number text keyboard and full text keyboard)

Any suggestion may help, thanks you very much.

```
public class SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener

    @Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
        super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

        // Reset our state.  We want to do this even if restarting, because
        // the underlying state of the text editor could have changed in any way.
        mComposing.setLength(0);
        updateCandidates();

        if (!restarting) {
            // Clear shift states.
            mMetaState = 0;
        }

        boolean isEditText = true;

        mPredictionOn = false;
        mCompletionOn = false;
        mCompletions = null;

        //TODO: setup own behavior
        // We are now going to initialize our state based on the type of
        // text being edited.
        switch (attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_CLASS) {
            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER:
                mCurKeyboard = mNumberKeyboard;
                break;

            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME:
                // Numbers and dates default to the symbols keyboard, with
                // no extra features.
                mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
                break;

            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE:
                // Phones will also default to the symbols keyboard, though
                // often you will want to have a dedicated phone keyboard.
                mCurKeyboard = mSymbolsKeyboard;
                break;

            case InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT:
                // This is general text editing.  We will default to the
                // normal alphabetic keyboard, and assume that we should
                // be doing predictive text (showing candidates as the
                // user types).
                mCurKeyboard = mQwertyKeyboard;
                mPredictionOn = true;

                // We now look for a few special variations of text that will
                // modify our behavior.
                int variation = attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_MASK_VARIATION;
                if (variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD ||
                        variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD) {
                    // Do not display predictions / what the user is typing
                    // when they are entering a password.
                    mPredictionOn = false;
                }

                if (variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_EMAIL_ADDRESS
                        || variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_URI
                        || variation == InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_FILTER) {
                    // Our predictions are not useful for e-mail addresses
                    // or URIs.
                    mPredictionOn = false;
                }

                if ((attribute.inputType & InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE) != 0) {
                    // If this is an auto-complete text view, then our predictions
                    // will not be shown and instead we will allow the editor
                    // to supply their own.  We only show the editor's
                    // candidates when in fullscreen mode, otherwise relying
                    // own it displaying its own UI.
                    mPredictionOn = false;
                    mCompletionOn = isFullscreenMode();
                }

                // We also want to look at the current state of the editor
                // to decide whether our alphabetic keyboard should start out
                // shifted.
                updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
                break;

            default:
                // For all unknown input types, default to the alphabetic
                // keyboard with no special features.
                mCurKeyboard = mNonEditTextKeyboard;
                updateShiftKeyState(attribute);
                isEditText = false;
        }

        // Update the label on the enter key, depending on what the application
        // says it will do.
        mCurKeyboard.setImeOptions(getResources(), attribute.imeOptions);

        if ((mInputView!= null) && (!isEditText)) {
            //TODO: handle non edit text case.
            handleClose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My code on input keyboard service (not activity):

```
@Override public void onStartInput(EditorInfo attribute, boolean restarting) {
    super.onStartInput(attribute, restarting);

    ...

    if ((getCurrentInputConnection() != null) && (!isEditText))
        getCurrentInputConnection().performEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT);
    }
}
```

However, I propose dont put keycode 10 \n Enter on your keyboard but using code -4 IME ActionDone. In my example it works so much better since it let the application make focus choice, it will skip non object text and clear focus properly.

Answer (score 1):

To modify enter behaviour on the soft keyboard you will have to create a custom EditText class and override onCreateInputConnections. See my example below in which I always display 'Done' instead of next when users are on this specific EditText.

```
@Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(@NonNull EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        InputConnection connection = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
        int imeActions = outAttrs.imeOptions&EditorInfo.IME_MASK_ACTION;
        if ((imeActions&EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) != 0) {
            // clear the existing action
            outAttrs.imeOptions ^= imeActions;
            // set the DONE action
            outAttrs.imeOptions |= EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
        }
        if ((outAttrs.imeOptions&EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION) != 0) {
            outAttrs.imeOptions &= ~EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_ENTER_ACTION;
        }
        return connection;
    }
```

You can also set which EditTexts should gain focus next in your layout with

```
android:nextFocusDown=""
```

passing in the id of the EditText you want to be focused next.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I'm working on keyboard service and it does not bind to an specific activity. I wonder how Android default soft keyboard work? How can it skip non edit text object and focus to the next edit text?

Comment: It should do that by default. Which view is it going to? Or is it just crashing?

Comment: Ah I see the checkboxes.. You can play around with setting focusable on different objects. For example if you don't want the radio buttons to be focusable you can setFocusable(false) on them. But nextFocusDown should do the trick?

Comment: android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false" on the CheckBox object

Comment: The problem is : it always focus on the next object: checkbox, button, ... So I dont want to set all these objects. Can we do something like android default soft keyboard? How android ASOP skip non edit text objects?

Comment: I can't really know exactly what to do without looking at you're code in detail. But I'd imagine it's along the lines of checking if the next view if an instance of EditText (if (View instanceof EditText)) and if it is proceeding to change the focus.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I updated the code (it's nealy the same sample code of Android). For the moment I close keyboard when the object was detected as a non edit text object. However, I looking for sth like the behavior of Android default keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Use the android:nextFocusDown param to specify which field you'd like to get focus when the user hits the enter key.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of stuff like this in my layouts, so I'm looking for a solution on input keyboard service (like default keyboard).

Comment: Well you define it only once in you XML, it is pretty automatic.

Comment: You can also make the checkboxs not focusable.

Comment: Checkbox is only a example, my keyboard focus on other object like button, image, ... too :(

Comment: Each time I hit enter, it focus to the next object (for the moment, I cannot list all type but at least it focused on checkbox and button)

Comment: android:nextFocusDown works with object ID. And I'm woking with a lot of edit text + check box form so it will take a lof of time to setting all edit text objects :( In addition, when we need to add new forms, I will have to check all edit texts. It will not be easy. :(

Comment: Coding is not always easy my friend.